# What is the term for road rage?

Tags: word-requests

I tried to explain this term to a friend with no luck. Thank you.

Comment: Description in bottom entry: http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no word in Japanese that means 'road rage'.

1. If a listener knows 'road rage'

You can say [ロードレージ](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8).

2. If a listener doesn't know 'road rage'

You can say:

> 車に乗ると人が変わること

Comment: 「車に乗ると人が変わる**人** 、豹変する**人** 」(人を指して言う)というより「車に乗ると人が変わる**こと** 、豹変する**こと** 」(そうなる状態とか心理状態を指して言う)みたいですけど。。

Comment: 「車に乗ると人が変わる人」doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @paullb It makes great sense to me. Whether it's a good translation is another matter.

Comment: @Shoko そうでしたね、Wikiをよく読んでませんでした

Comment: @paullb  「車に乗ると人が変わる人」 makes sense and is a natural phrase. 人が変わる is an expression meaning "their personality/character changes", so 車に乗ると*人が変わる*人 literally means "someone who changes their personality when driving."

Comment: @Shoko Road Rage isn't somebody who "changes their personality when driving" it is somebody who becomes enraged while driving is something completely different. 車の運転中に突然キレること is more accurate.

Comment: @paullb I know. That's what I said in my first comment above. Please read: `「車に乗ると人が変わる人、豹変する人」(人を指して言う)というより「車に乗ると人が変わること、豹変すること」(そうなる状態とか心理状態を指して言う)みたいです`. In my 2nd comment I just said 車に乗ると人が変わる人 is a natural phrase. I didn't mean to say 車に乗ると人が変わる人 means "Road Rage."

Comment: @Shoko Then I think you should write that as an answer and have it accepted. Either way, this answer as written is clearly not the best answer out of all those given.

Comment: `you should write that as an answer`<- なんで？私のコメントを受けて、sun-solar-arrow さんは「車に乗ると人が変わる人」を「車に乗ると人が変わること」に変えたんだし、もういいと思いますけど。

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea to explain with a word.  But if I explain it in Japanese,

> road rage ってのは、ほら、ハンドル持つと人が変わるって人いるよね。ちょっとした渋滞なんかでもすぐ舌打ちしてクラクション鳴らしたりしてさ。あれだよあれ。

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a word except for the Katakana already presented but a consise description would be 車{くるま}の運転中{うんてんちゅう}に突然{とつぜん}キレること

Answer (score 0):

Could   居直り (いなおり)  be used? It means "change of attitude" and refers to someone suddenly turning aggressive or violent. It is used, for example, of a burglar who is disturbed by the person whose home he has broken into thinking it was empty and reacts by committing murder or rape.

Comment: 「居直り」「居直り強盗」とは言いますが、「居直り運転」とかはありません。

Comment: Shoko-san, Thanks for your comment. Graham.